# SQL in python jupyter. Can't drop a column

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

I am learning SQL. I know basically nothing about it.

This in my code in the Jupyter notebook.

```
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite://

%%sql
CREATE TABLE Store (Store_ID, Store Location, Opening_Year)

 * sqlite://
Done.

%%sql
ALTER TABLE Store DROP Store Location

 * sqlite://
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "DROP": syntax error [SQL: 'ALTER TABLE Store DROP Store Location'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `COLUMN`:

```
ALTER TABLE Store DROP COLUMN Store Location
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use underscores for your column names. Then, you do not need to use quotes or brackets so that SQLite recognises the column name as an identifier:

```
CREATE TABLE Store (Store_ID, Store_Location, Opening_Year);
```

However, if you must have a space in the column name, use quotes. The [SQLite Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) says that you can use single quotes, double quotes or square brackets. But I recommend using double quotes for identifiers, so that your code is more portable:

```
CREATE TABLE Store (Store_ID, "Store Location", Opening_Year);
```

Also, SQLite doesn't support `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN` syntax. To achieve the same result, use the same method as described in the [SQLite Tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE Store RENAME TO temp_Store;

CREATE TABLE Store (Store_ID, Opening_Year);

INSERT INTO Store 
SELECT Store_ID, Opening_Year
FROM temp_Store;

DROP TABLE temp_Store;

COMMIT;
```